# How does `(sum & operand) === operand` work in the following code? (Bitwise And)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

The following code checks if `sum` has `operand`, the code is very straightforward, but I'm confused by the condition `(sum & operand) === operand`.

I've read the [Bitwise AND (&)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_AND) doc, confused me even more, can someone explain it in simple terms?

```js
const has = (sum, operand) => (sum & operand) === operand

console.log(has(7, 4))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of code is usually used when you are working with **bitflags**. Essentially you want to check if the *operand* bits are set in the *sum* aswell.

The binary representation of 7 is `00000111`, while the binary representation of 4 is `00000100`.

By performing the bitwise AND operation `A & B` you are "preserving" the identical bits between the two, while setting all other bits to 0. Comparing the result with `B` again yields you the insight if all bits that are set in `B` are also set in `A`.